# AngularJS filter using multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to filter my user array using two input boxes.

This is the structure of my array:

> ```
>     $scope.users = [{
>     id: 1,
>     fname: 'Sophia',
>     lname: 'Smith',
>     email: 'sophia@mail.com'
> }...
> ```

My input boxes are called nameSearch and emailSearch. I want to search fname and lname properies with nameSearch, and at the same time apply emailSearch to the email property.

I find that when I use a simple filter like | filter: nameSearch, it searches the entire array object. I want to limit it to only search using fname, lname and email.

I've read the documentation and tried something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{fname: nameSearch, lname: nameSearch, email: emailSearch}">{{user.fname + ' ' + user.lname}}</li>
```

But it doesn't work the way I would have thought it should.

Do I have to write a custom filter for this to work?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0keyyo7m/)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), and especially the description of the `expression` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

If you use all filter, the combination is an AND of all search.

you could use a basic search, with:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter: nameSearch ">{{user.fname + ' ' + user.lname}}</li>
```

and it will retrieve any fields with your search.

If you need to filter more specifically some fields, you can make a function for that action, using OR logic.

Comment: "filter: nameSearch" will filter everything in the object. So if I have a property thats called maidenName for instance, it will be included in the filter aswell. I want nameSearch to only search the fname and lname fields.